# How do i use OSGi managed services and Configuration Admin to store configuration objects?

Tags: java, osgi

I am trying to get my head around using the org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedService and Configuration Admin for Apache Felix.

I understand that the ConfigurationAdmin pushes new configurations to the service via the method

```
public void updated(Dictionary<String, ?> dctnr) throws ConfigurationException
```

But i have a few questions:

1. The method signature seems to suggest that i can persist any configuration item in the Configuration, given the `Dictionary<String, ?>`. Is this the case, or is it only String values that you can use for configuration values? I have yet to find an example that uses anything but Strings.
2. Given that you can persist Objects as configuration values, what conventions must i follow in order for the Configuration Admin to actually persist them? Must they be Java Beans, or Serializable or JaxB enabled or maybe something else entirely?
3. Can i somehow get some information out of the Configuration Admin describing the type of the Object that is returned for a particular key?
   Say that i put a Date in one key, and a String in another, does the application just have to retain this knowledge, or can I get the information from the ManagedService somehow?

Answer (score 1):

The configuration object is defined in the Configuration Admin spec (see [OSGi Compendium Release 5 Specification](https://osgi.org/download/r5/osgi.cmpn-5.0.0.pdf)) as a dictionary of properties. Property values are referred to as the primary property types as defined in the Core spec.

This is the definition of primary property types in [OSGi Core Release 5 Specification](https://osgi.org/download/r5/osgi.core-5.0.0.pdf):

```
type ::= scalar | collection | array
scalar ::= String | Integer | Long | Float | Double | Byte | Short | Character | Boolean
primitive ::= int | long | float | double | byte | short | char | boolean
array ::= <Array of primitive> | <Array of scalar>
collection ::= <Collection of scalar>
```